# Tell when multiple onLoad events have been completed in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload-event

I have to load two apis.  The YouTube api which calls `onYouTubePlayerReady` when it has loaded and another api for SoundManager which calls `soundManager.onready(...)` when it has loaded.  I do a lot of stuff in each of these `ready` functions to prepare the site.  However, I also need to know when both have completed so I can do more initialization that require both to be fully loaded.  Any idea how to have a function that is called when both of these `ready` functions are called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a callback for both of them.

```
var callback = (function(){

    var count = 0;

    return function(){
         count++;
         if(count === 2){
            //both ran and do something
         }
    }

})();
```

Then in the end of both onloads just do:

```
callback();
```

The things in that if statement will only run on the second time this function i s called.

Small fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/2X8rF/

Comment: @Raynos haha i did not even know abt that :-P

Comment: @AlexisK No problemo ^_^ happy to help

Answer (score 1):

Just set a couple flags:

```
var aDone = false;
var bDone = false;

function whenADone(){
  // do your other stuff

  aDone = true;

  if(bDone) whenBothDone();
}

function whenBDone(){
  // do your other stuff

  bDone = true;

  if(aDone) whenBothDone();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a better way with Defered's, but this is simple and should work.  Just keep track of what loaded and what didn't.

```
var status = {
  youtube: false,
  sound: false
};

var loaded = function() {
  if (!status.youtube) return;
  if (!status.sound) return;

  // load stuff!
};

var onYoutubePlayerReady = function() {
  status.youtube = true;
  loaded();
};

soundManager.onready = function() {
  status.sound = true;
  loaded();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [jQuery deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), you could build promises for each ready function and combine them with [jQuery.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to trigger a final action. For example

```
function promiseYoutube() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    window.onYoutubePlayerReady = function() {
        console.log("Youtube");
        dfd.resolve();
    };
    return dfd.promise();
}

function promiseSoundManager() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    window.soundManager.onready = function() {
        console.log("SoundManager");
        dfd.resolve();
    };
    return dfd.promise();
}

$.when( promiseYoutube(), promiseSoundManager() ).then(function(){
    console.log('Youtube+SoundManager');
});
```

And a Fiddle simulating these callbacks http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/hCznB/

Comment: very cool.  Thanks for the great answer.  It would work but is a little more complex for the problem.  I will definitely keep this in mind for next time though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could have both of your `readys` set a boolean to true then test against those a `$(document).ready(function () { if (youTube === true && soundManager === true) { // Do stuff }});`

Answer (score 0):

If using jQuery, take a look at deferred:

http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/

http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Thanks

Comment: Answers with links only are not as useful, please explain how a deferred is helpful in this case. A link is fine, but I shouldn't have to go to a different page to know what you mean. A link for further explanation is fine.